# HealthVault Manually add (upload) CCD xml and export (download) CCD xml in C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, ccd, healthvault

Right now we have two problems:

1. Is it possible to do manually CCD add (upload) function in C#?

We have the working code of CCD upload function with "auto commit" as following:
[image]

And this will "auto commit" all data in the uploaded CCD xml file as shown below. 
[image]

However, we want to upload CCD xml file with "Manually commit" as following:
[image]

Here, the user actually has an option (Add items) to add item manually into measurement or not after the user upload a CCD xml file.

We want to have a similar function for user to manually choose the items to be added as well (rather than just auto commit all data).

So, is it possible to implement "Manually commit" as I did "auto commit" above in C#? How to do it...?

2. Is it possible to implement "Export" CCD function as HeathVault in C#?

Our goal is to implement a download CCD function which returns the same result as "Export" on HealthVault.
[image]
[image]

Then we got an Exported file and its name is "User name.xml"

What we tried so far is:
[image]

Then we can get the CCDs xml files (CCD_0~CCD_2 on my account) on HealthVault:
[image]

However, these CCD xml files (even if combine these CCD into one file) are completely different from "User name.xml" (which is using the "Export" function to export CCD file on HealthVault).

We think the difference is that the CCD_0~CCD_2 file we got are just the CCD files user upload. 
And HealthVault will take user committed upload file to read and write into one HealthVault's own user personal CCD xml file.

And then the "Export" function export the only one HealthVault's own user personal CCD xml file.
If it is not correct, could you please explain how HeathVault merge committed uploaded CCD xml files into one user personal CCD xml file?

And is it possible to implement the "Export" CCD function as HeathVault page in C#? How to do it...?

Any idea or discussion is appreciated.

Comment: There's a lot of information in this question. You should consider reducing the amount of information and the questions if you'd like to receive a solid response. You should also post your code in the question instead of using screenshots as it will help future users when they use google.

Comment: Thank you for comment. This is my first time post a question in the stackoverflow, and your comment here is great. So, I think I will take your suggestions and  separate the two questions in this post into two post and make the code here better to see.

Comment: you should look at the guidelines for writing a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) @QCCSresearchteam

Comment: The answer is probably yes.  I suspect you are working with HL7 xml medical records and there a lots of options for modifying records.  HL7 was developed for the medical community by the IEEE to electronically transfer medical records between providers and insurers.  See website : http://www.hl7.org/